# SoapVar can't be extended

Tags: php, soap

Right now I do something like this:

```
$xmlVar = [..];
$var = new \SoapVar([$xmlVar], SOAP_ENC_OBJECT)

$client->__soapCall('functionName', [$var], null, [$header]);
```

Now, when I wrap SoapVar into my own class (empty class, with no body) like this:

```
class SVar extends \SoapVar { }
```

and change above code to:

```
$xmlVar = [..];
$var = new SVar([$xmlVar], SOAP_ENC_OBJECT)

$client->__soapCall('functionName', [$var], null, [$header]);
```

I am getting error: `SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'someProperty' property`.

I was comparing `print_r($var)` from both situations and only difference was class name. Both contain exact same value. Why wrapping \SoapVar into empty object doesn't work? Does SOAP internally check exact type and if it is not exactly SoapVar it treats it as StdObject or what?
I tried exact same thing on `SoapHeader` and it works with no problems.

Comment: Can you show de `SVar` class?

Comment: I already did. Whole `SVar` class is above in my question. Nothing in it, just 1 line of code with simple extend. This is why this is so weird - simple class extension breaks soap call.
Here is diff between classes: https://www.diffchecker.com/sOWUP1yd

Comment: Can you add a empty constructor to the class?

Comment: Weird question. Of course I could do that but this would override original constructor and nothing would happen, right (I would create SoapVar without any parameters)?